# Decting Users Smile, Blinking and Looking to side on mobile Platforms

Tags: android, ios, image-processing, windows-phone-8, face-detection

I would like to implement an App for iOS, Android and Windows Phone where the user can control action with "face gestures":

When he smiles an image should be taken. When he is blinking an option screen should be shown. When he turns his head to the left, the left option should be chosen.

Is this possible for all three platforms? For iOS I think it should be possible with CIDetectorEyeBlink and CIDetectorSmile. But I still don't know if it is possible to detect head movements.

And I haven't any clue regarding the other platforms. Do you know any resources that could help me? It would be great if there are SDKs to solve my tasks for all three platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest OpenCV library for such things.
http://opencv.org/